# how do you change screens from python file in KIVY

Tags: python, screen, kivy

All the tutorials in the internet show how to use the ScreenManager and change different screens from the .kv files. 
I am still learning and I can not manage to control it from the .py file.

I want my app first to perform some validation before starting. There fore i want Kivy app to start with a simple "Please wait" screen, and after that to go to the Main screen.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of how one can change a screen from the python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    Button:
        on_press: root.on_click()

<Screen2>:
    name: 'screen2'
    Label:
        text: "Cool!"

<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
""")

class Screen1(Screen):

    def on_click(self):
        sm.current = 'screen2'

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = MyScreenManager()
        return sm

SimpleApp().run()
```

I have used the button on_press event to call the python code but you can run your validations in another thread and when your are done you can call back to the kivy code using the *Clock* api